# Object Attribute in Random List Not Accessible in Python

Tags: python, random, object, oop

I'm working on my first object oriented bit of python and I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import random 

class triangle:

# Angle A To Angle C Connects Side F
# Angle C to Angle B Connects Side D
# Angle B to Angle A Connects Side E

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f

    #def solver:
        #pass

#initialize Triangle
myTri = triangle(0,0,0,0,0,0)

#Pick Three Random Angles or Sides to Generate Values For
sample = random.sample([myTri.a, myTri.b, myTri.c, myTri.d, myTri.e, myTri.f],  3)

#Sets the three randomly picked variables to a Random Number



sample[0] = random.randint(1, 100)
sample[1] = random.randint(1, 100)
sample[2] = random.randint(1, 100)
```

How do I pass myTri.a, for example to random.randint.  It is passing the value of '0' which it initialized.  I want to be able to assign a random value to three of the .a-.f attributes of myTri.  What am I missing?

Comment: I presume that you are going to check that the random assignments to attributes result in valid triangles. Your triangles are rather over-specified; you need only 3 attributes (e.g. length of each side, or 2 lengths and the contained angle) and the other 3 attributes are derived. Perhaps you need to think about that a bit before you go assigning random values to the attributes. Convention is to call your class Triangle, not triangle. Classes are not "initialized"; what you are doing there is creating one (invalid!) Triangle instance and naming it "myTri". Ugh, please read PEP8. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your input. 1. I've change Triangle to match PEP8.  I've googled this and bookmarked it.  I'll use this in the future to clarify how things should be styled. 2. I don't understand what you mean by invalid.  Do you mean mathematically or pythonically invalid?  I am working on checking to make sure ABC (the three angles) don't exceed 180.

3. Not sure what you mean by "Maybe you need to think about this..." as I'm not sure what "this" is.  The idea here is that the program will be able to solve the missing angles/sides if given enough information.

Comment: Mathematically valid. Sum of 3 angles must be EXACTLY 180 degrees. That leaves you with one variable side length and two derivable side lengths. "this" is the validity-ensuring exercise. If you get 3 angles that magically add to 180, the sides will all be zero; how do you propose to solve for the missing 3 sides??

Comment: I assumed that was the point of randomly assigning to only 3 properties. If you get SAS or SSS you can solve for the others, if you get ASS or AAA you can't and you display something...

Comment: John Kugelman you are correct.  This is basically to determine all knowable information about a given triangle knowing only three properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `[myTri.a, myTri.b, ...]` you are not getting a list of the variables themselves,  or references to them. Instead you are getting just their values. Since you know they were initialized to `0`, it is as if you had written `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. There's no difference.

Then later when you try to assign to `sample[0]`, you are actually just overwriting the 0 that is stored in that array with a random value. Python knows nothing at all about `myTri` at that point; the connection is lost.

Here's what you can do to get the effect you're aiming for. First, pass a list of variable names we want to assign to later to `random.sample`:

```
sample = random.sample(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 3)
```

That'll give us back 3 random variable names. Now we want to assign to the variables with those same names. We can do that by using the special `setattr` function, which takes an object and a variable name and sets its value. For instance, `setattr(myTri, "b", 72)` does the same thing as `myTri.b = 72`. So rewritten we have:

```
setattr(myTri, sample[0], random.randint(1, 100))
setattr(myTri, sample[1], random.randint(1, 100))
setattr(myTri, sample[2], random.randint(1, 100))
```

The major concept here is that you're doing a bit of reflection, also known as introspection. You've got dynamic variable names--you don't know exactly who you're messing with--so you've got to consult with some more exotic, out of the way language constructs. Normally I'd actually caution against such tomfoolery, but this is a rare instance where introspection is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

To assign to `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
myTri.a = random.randint(1, 100)
myTri.b = random.randint(1, 100)
myTri.c = random.randint(1, 100)
```

To assign to one random attribute from `a`-`f`:

```
attrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
setattr(myTri, random.choice(attrs), random.randint(1, 100))
```

To assign to three random attributes from `a`-`f`:

```
attrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
for attr in random.sample(attrs, 3):
  setattr(myTri, attr, random.randint(1, 100))
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't work for my application as I don't want to set just the first three.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't.  It makes sense now! 

Is there any reason to do this over the previous poster?

Comment: Previous? Mine was posted first by 1 minute. :P We both have the same answer, using setattr(), the differences are superficial.

Comment: Okay, I assumed they were superficial, but I'm to the point now where I really want to learn python and really understand what's going on instead of hacking my way through it.  Sorry, you're correct, you were 1 minute faster!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to using setattr: do it when you create a Triangle instance.

```
args = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in xrange(3)] + [0, 0, 0]
random.shuffle(args)
my_tri = Triangle(*args)
```